# Cropping an image in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba

I need to crop an image on a Powerpoint slide using VBA - in my particular case I'm cropping from the top and left edges.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following commands will crop 10 points off of each edge of the shape:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) 
  .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 10
  .PictureFormat.CropTop = 10
  .PictureFormat.CropRight = 10
  .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 10
End With
```

Note that this will crop shape number 1 on slide 1.  If you want to crop the currently selected shape, use the following as the first line instead:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
```

See additional information on the CropBottom/etc. properties here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.pictureformat.cropbottom