# Subscript out of range error when trying to copy Excel charts to Power Point presentation

Tags: vba, excel, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to copy charts from excel to PPT in a PPT macro using a function.  Though, when I try to run the function it says "Subscript out of range" on the line indicated below and I am really confused why.

```
Public dlgOpen As FileDialog
Public folder As String
Public excelApp As Object
Public xlWorkBook As Object
Public xlWorkBook2 As Object
Public PPT As Presentation
Public Name1 As String
Public Name2 As String
Public rng1 As Range
Public rng2 As Range
Dim NamedRange As Range


Public Sub GenerateVisual()
    Set PPT = ActivePresentation
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = True

    Set xlWorkBook = excelApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wzawisa\Downloads\MarketSegmentTotals.xls")
    xlWorkBook.Sheets("MarketSegmentTotals").Activate
    xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range("MarketSegmentTotals!$A$1:$F$2")
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "DD Ready by Market Segment"
    xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add

    With xlWorkBook.ActiveChart.Parent
        .Top = 100    ' reposition
        .Left = 100   ' reposition
    End With

    Set xlWorkBook2 = excelApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wzawisa\Downloads\GeneralTotals.xls")
    xlWorkBook2.Sheets("Totals").Activate
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet.Range("Totals!$A$1:$C$2")
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Total DD Ready"
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add

    With xlWorkBook2.ActiveChart.Parent
        .Top = 100    ' reposition
        .Left = 100   ' reposition
    End With

    Set rng1 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("MarketSegmentTotals").Range("B8:F25")
    Set rng2 = xlWorkBook2.Sheets("Totals").Range("A8:C25")

    Call RangeToPresentation("MarketSegmentTotals", rng1)
    Call RangeToPresentation("Totals", rng2)

    'Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    '
    'dlgOpen.Show
    'dlgOpen.Title = "Select Report Location"
    '
    'folder = dlgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

End Sub


Public Function RangeToPresentation(sheetName, NamedRange)
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object

    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal

    ' Select the last (blank slide)
    longSlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
    ppPres.Slides(1).Select

    Set PPSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

    xlWorkBook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(NamedRange.Address).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, _
        Format:=xlBitmap

    ' Paste the range
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

    'Set the image to lock the aspect ratio
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

    'Set the image size slightly smaller than width of the PowerPoint Slide
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = ppApp.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 10
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = ppApp.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 10

    'Shrink image if outside of slide borders
    If ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width > 700 Then
        ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700
    End If

    If ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height > 600 Then
        ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 600
    End If

    ' Align the pasted range
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True    

    ' Clean up
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set ppPres = Nothing
    Set ppApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Does this workbook exist? `C:\Users\wzawisa\Downloads\MarketSegmentTotals.xls`. If it does, does it have a sheet titled `MarketSegmentTotals`?

Comment: Yes. Both of those exist and are open. Thats what confuses me about why this error would appear.

Comment: I fixed this issue but now, at the new line indicated in the edit it says the "Object doesn't support that property or method." I'm not sure why.

Comment: For starters, you will want to flip the order of your calls to `RangeToPresentation`

Comment: Well, for one thing the `Workbook` class does not have a `.NamedRange` property.  You could use the `.Names(..)` collection if you supply the name of the the Named Range.

Comment: Correct @RBarryYoung so if you wanted to get this working (which I wouldn't suggest doing it this way, there is more to fix) you could probably do `xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range(NamedRange.Address).CopyPicture ...`

Comment: Whoops. Ok, I changed that line to `xlWorkBook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(NamedRange).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, _
        Format:=xlBitmap`

Which I thought would solve my issue but it is still saying "Application or object defined error."

Comment: @jaysunice3401 Not sure, he doesnt declare anything explicitly, so I'm not sure what type/state the `NamedRange` parameter/variable is by the time it gets there.  And I agree, there's other problems here..

Comment: What other problems?

Comment: I think it's coming through as variant. So yes, my comment probably isn't going to work unless you `dim rng1 as Range` and then `set rng1`.

Comment: Try declaring `rng1, rng2` as Ranges, use `Set ..` on their assignments and then use @jaysunice3401's code: `...Range(NamedRange.Address)...` instead.

Comment: @jaysunice3401 My thoughts exactly.

Comment: I made your suggested edits but now it is back to saying "Subscript out of range" at `xlWorkBook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(NamedRange.Address).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, _ Format:=xlBitmap` @RBarryYoung

Comment: Hmm, try changing the whole line to just `NamedRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap`.

Comment: Oh!  You know what, according to the 2003 VBA doc, `xlBitmap` is a `Format:=` value, and `xlScreen` is an `Appearance:=` value, *but* according to the current .Net interop doc, it's the other way around.  Not sure which is right, so try reversing them, if the previous comment doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are mixing `Range`s. Please try the code posted below, which contains quite a few modifications from your original code. I detail below the main ones. You have to set a reference to the *Microsoft Excel vvv Object Library*. In the VBE, use *Tools* -> *References*.

Main changes:

1. Declared the type of arguments in your `Function`.
2. Changed the `Function` to `Sub` (you only perform actions, you do not return a value).
3. Used `NamedRange` directly. There is no need for the convoluted way in which you used it. The first argument is now superfluous (you may remove it).
4. Used variables to refer to objects. This allows for much easier coding and debugging.
5. Removed some of the `Select` and `Activate`. You should not use them unless strictly needed (apparently this is not the case).

There are still quite a few points where you can improve your code, in particular along the lines set above.
Please first try it. If it does not work, use the debugger, watches and the immediate window to explore deeper, and give feedback.

```
Option Explicit

Public dlgOpen As FileDialog
Public folder As String
Public excelApp As Object
Public xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Public xlWorkBook2 As Excel.Workbook
Public PPT As Presentation
Public Name1 As String
Public Name2 As String
Public rng1 As Excel.Range
Public rng2 As Excel.Range
Dim NamedRange As Excel.Range
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsh As Excel.Shape
Dim xlch As Excel.Chart
Dim xlws2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsh2 As Excel.Shape
Dim xlch2 As Excel.Chart

Public Sub GenerateVisual()
    Set PPT = ActivePresentation
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = True

    Set xlWorkBook = excelApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wzawisa\Downloads\MarketSegmentTotals.xls")
    Set xlws = xlWorkBook.Sheets("MarketSegmentTotals")
    Set xlsh = xlws.Shapes.AddChart
    Set xlch = xlsh.Chart
    With xlch
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=xlws.Range("$A$1:$F$2")
        .Legend.Delete
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
        .ChartTitle.Text = "DD Ready by Market Segment"
    End With
    xlws.ListObjects.Add

    With xlch.Parent
        .Top = 100    ' reposition
        .Left = 100   ' reposition
    End With

    Set xlWorkBook2 = excelApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wzawisa\Downloads\GeneralTotals.xls")
    Set xlws2 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Totals")
    'xlWorkBook2.Sheets("Totals").Activate
    Set xlsh2 = xlws2.Shapes.AddChart
    Set xlch2 = xlsh2.Chart
    With xlch2
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=xlws2.Range("$A$1:$C$2")
        .Legend.Delete
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Total DD Ready"
    End With
    xlWorkBook2.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add

    With xlws2.Parent
        .Top = 100    ' reposition
        .Left = 100   ' reposition
    End With

    Set rng1 = xlws.Range("B8:F25")
    Set rng2 = xlws2.Range("A8:C25")

    Call RangeToPresentation("MarketSegmentTotals", rng1)
    Call RangeToPresentation("Totals", rng2)

    'Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    '
    'dlgOpen.Show
    'dlgOpen.Title = "Select Report Location"
    '
    'folder = dlgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

End Sub


Public Sub RangeToPresentation(ByVal sheetName As String, NamedRange As Excel.Range)
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal

    ' Select the last (blank slide)
    Dim longSlideCount As Integer
    longSlideCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
    ppPres.Slides(1).Select    
    Set PPSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

    NamedRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

    ' Paste the range
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

    'Set the image to lock the aspect ratio
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

    'Set the image size slightly smaller than width of the PowerPoint Slide
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = ppApp.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 10
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = ppApp.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 10

    'Shrink image if outside of slide borders
    If ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width > 700 Then
        ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700
    End If
    If ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height > 600 Then
        ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 600
    End If

    ' Align the pasted range
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

    ' Clean up
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set ppPres = Nothing
    Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I get an error saying the object doesnt support the property or method on the first line of the first with statement setting the chart type.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: @Pablo - Try the edited code and post feedback. Please take the time to check the minor differences with the previous version. In case it works, I will remove most of the commented code (clutter).

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Now one more question, How would I crop the pictures once I get them in powerpoint?

Comment: @Pablo - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660428/cropping-an-image-in-powerpoint-using-vba